# Php and Javascript block

Tags: javascript, php, css, if-statement

I have a variable like this on PHP,

```
<div class="autcp">
      <?php
       if($GLOBALS['q']==""){
           echo "";
       }else if($GLOBALS['q']=="bb"){
           echo "cc";
       }
       ?>
</div>
```

CSS

```
width: 301px;
padding: 20px 22px 18px 22px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
border: 1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.3);
border-bottom-color: rgba(125,125,125,0.3);
```

What I want to do is do not show anything if it's empty

Comment: change your code to this `if (!empty($GLOBALS['q']) && $GLOBALS['q'] == "bb")
{
    echo "cc";
}`

Comment: if it's empty you don't want to show the empty div isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.autcp{
  width: 301px;
  padding: 20px 22px 18px 22px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
  border: 1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.3);
  border-bottom-color: rgba(125,125,125,0.3);
}
  <?php
   if(!empty($GLOBALS['q']) && $_GLOBALS['q']=='bb'){
      ?>
<div class="autcp">
 <?php
 echo "cc";
?>
</div>
<?php
   }
   ?>
```